# i need to pass url var in the scr of a iframe

Tags: url, iframe, var

i need to know how to pass everything after the .php part in this link

```
"http://wreckedclothing.net/help/view.php?e=john@wreckedclothing.net&t=985559"
```

to a iframe on the same page. "hosted on the same site"
like this

```
"<iframe>
      src="http://www.wreckedclothing.net/help.php?e=john@wreckedclothing.net&t=985559"
      frameborder="0"
      width="829"
      name="tree"></iframe>
```

see how it adds everything to the link in src

Answer (score 2):

`$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` contains the query string ("everything after the .php part", except the "?", that is).

So if you're in a php-page, you could do something like this:

```
<iframe src=[YOUR_URL_HERE]?<?php echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; ?>></iframe>
```

to pass the whole query-string that has been send to the page containing the iframe to the src of the iframe.

Comment: omg thank you i been looking for hours for how to fix this. man that was so simple too lol. thnx again